# Window loses cursor lock when using media controls

Tags: league-of-legends, linux

I'm running league of legends on debian (don't ask why), and whenever I use media controls (for example play/pause, next/previous track), the game loses the cursor lock, which makes it impossible to properly control the camera in game.

How can I avoid this (other than not using media controls)? Anyone with any experience with this?

Comment: sounds like your media controls changes the focus from the game, to whichever media player you are using

Comment: I thought so too at first, but then I noticed the game doesn't drop fps which usually happens whenever it loses focus.

Comment: Do you have a red border around your game if this happens?

Comment: No, I know about that F9 thing ;)

Comment: I think the easiest workaround would be to play in windowed mode. This way you can check better if you actually lose focus. And if you lose focus, a simple click into the game window should regain focus. Otherwise I'd think that your issue is more on the OS side than the clients side

Answer (score 1):

When that happens to me (sometimes when I load in game I just do not have Cursor Lock) I just alt+tab out of the game and back in. and that seems to wake up the game that its supposed to have the lock on.

I play windowed full screen, if that helps you.